# error:there is more than one instance of the overloaded function "min" corresponding to the argument list:

Tags: c++, функции

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

constexpr int divider = 3;
constexpr int INF = 1 << 30;

template<typename T>
const T& min(const T& a, const T& b) {
    return a < b ? a : b;
}

template<int V>
struct initialized_int
{
    int value = V;
    initialized_int() {}
    operator int() { return value; }
    initialized_int(int _v) : value(_v) {}

    template<int V1, int V2>
    friend bool operator < (const initialized_int<V1>& a, const initialized_int<V2>& b) {
        return a.value < b.value;
    }
};

int main() {

    ifstream input("27-A (1).txt");
    input.exceptions(ios::failbit);

    int n;
    input >> n;
    map<int, initialized_int<INF> > firstThirsty, secondThirsty;

    int minim = INF;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int tmp;
        input >> tmp;
        int rem = tmp % divider;
        minim = min(tmp + secondThirsty[rem ? divider - rem : 0], minim);
        for (auto entry : firstThirsty) {
            auto& consistent = secondThirsty[(entry.first + rem) % divider];
            consistent = min(consistent, initialized_int<INF>(entry.second + tmp));
        }
        firstThirsty[rem] = min(firstThirsty[rem], initialized_int<INF>(tmp));
    }
    input.close();
    cout << minim;
    return 0;
}
```

what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

В наличии в стандартной библиотеке функции `min`...

Если вы точно укажете, какую именно функцию использовать (например, вашу -

```
minim = ::min(tmp + secondThirsty[rem ? divider - rem : 0], minim);
```

или библиотечную

```
minim = std::min(tmp + secondThirsty[rem ? divider - rem : 0], minim);
```

(т.е. использовать полностью квалифицированное имя) проблемы не станет.

Comment: that is, to connect the algorithm library?

Comment: Здесь Stack Overflow на русском языке, перейдите на него, pls...

Comment: а да сори,спасибо